# actionSubmit without Button

Tags: grails, gsp

How can I use the <g:actionSubmit without having the button, i'd like to have text instead. My issue is that I want to show text and not a button.

Here is an example;

```
<span>
   <g:actionSubmit controller="controllername" action="actionname"  name="updateStatus" data-status="approved" value="${message(code: 'default.button.activate.label', default: 'Approve')}"/>
</span>
```

Comment: You can use CSS to display your button as text. Otherwise you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: "How can I use the <g:actionSubmit without having the button" - That doesn't really make sense.  The `actionSubmit` tag is specifically for creating a button.  Are you wanting to generate an anchor tag?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, you can use OnEvent in javascript to submit. it is quite common trick to have hidden forms that submit onEvent. Keep in mind you are talking about the 'view' so this can have javascript in it as well.